# Returning phantom typed value with data kinds

Tags: haskell, data-kinds

I am parsing some input, for which I have something similar to this:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures #-}
data InputKind = A | B | C
data Input (kind :: InputKind) =
    InputA Char
  | InputB Double String
  | InputC Int String
```

And then I have my parsing functions:

```hs
parseA :: Parser (Either SomeError (Input 'A))
parseB :: Parser (Either SomeError (Input 'B))
parseC :: Parser (Either SomeError (Input 'C))
```

So, I am now interested in writing something that looks like this:

```hs
parse :: Parser (Either SomeError (Input (kind :: InputKind)))
```

Is there any way to write this in a way that types make sense?

Comment: What do you mean by "in a way that types make sense"? Everything seems to be working already... The one thing I would do is make `Input` a GADT so that the `kind :: InputKind` is `A` for `InputA`, `B` for `InputB`, and `C` for `InputC`.

Comment: The `parse` type signature is not valid haskell (at least not without some other extension, which the compiler does not tell)

Comment: Are you looking for `parse :: formal (kind :: InputKind). Parser (Either SomeError (Input kind))`?

Comment: The `parse` signature you give compiles fine w/ GHC versions 8.0.2 and 7.10.3, and the only needed extensions are the ones you list (DataKinds and KindSignatures). What GHC version are you using, and what error are you getting?

Comment: Keep in mind that if `foo :: Parser (Something (Input kind))`, then `kind` is chosen by the caller. Do you want `kind` to be chosen by the caller or by the parser? If the former, you probably need a singleton additional argument. If the latter, you need an existential type wrapper. In both cases, this might be the wrong approach to solve your actual problem -- it starts getting so complex that you might have an XY problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I need the kind to be chosen by the parser (it realizes something is of which kind when parsing). Indeed, it seems like it may be the wrong approach to solving the problem.